# Darle la función a "button" para parar un script

Tags: javascript, script, botón

Hola buenas estoy con un proyecto "final" que tenemos que hacer, un juego, página web o lo que queramos (sencillo)
Encontré en internet un "coche en movimiento" y parar mejorarlo intente hacer que se parar al darle a un botón y hacer exactamente lo mismo al volver a darle, pero para mi, con el conocimiento que tengo es imposible.
Aquí os dejo lo hecho. Gracias

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Último proyecto</title> 
</head>

<style type="text/css">
* { margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; }
h1 { font:bold 1.5em arial; text-align: center; padding: 0.5em ; } /* sirve para poner el texto central con el tipo de letra seleccionado*/
#visor { position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 200px; width: 450px; /*sirve para poner el texto en la posición seleccionada*/
         height: 300px; overflow: hidden; } /* características de la letra*/
#fondouno { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; } /*sirve para posicionar el fondo 1*/
#fondodos { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 450px; } /*sirve para posicionar el fondo*/
#micoche { position: absolute; top: 180px; left: 120px; } /*sirve para posicionar el coche*/
#Parar { position: absolute; right: 250px; top: 90px; color: red;  }
</style> 
<body>
<h1>Coche en movimiento</h1>
<div id="visor">
   <div id="fondouno">
      <img src="fondoCoche.gif" alt="fondo1" > <!--utilizamos alt para que si la imágen no carga aparezca el texto (fondo1) -->
   </div>
   <div id="fondodos">
      <img src="fondoCoche.gif" alt="fondo2" >
   </div> <!--utilizamos div para crear seccionas-->
   <div id="micoche">
      <img src="coche.gif" alt="elCoche" >
   <div> <!--En este apartado metenemos las imágenes con el código img y le damos un nombre (id) para nombrarlo más adelante-->
</div>
<div>
    <button id="Parar" input type="Parar"value="reiniciar" onclick="parar" name="resetear"> Parar </button>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { 
fondo1=document.getElementById("fondouno"); 
fondo2=document.getElementById("fondodos"); 
pararmover=setInterval(mover,50); // sirve para iniciar el temporizador
setInterval(repetir,2250); // sirve para iniciar el segundo temporizador
}
desplazar=0; 
function mover() { 
         desplazar-=10; // desplaza el fondo -10px
         desplazar2=desplazar+450; //sirve para mover el fondo 2 a la vez
         posicion1=desplazar+"px"; //preparar para código CSS fondo del fondo 1
         posicion2=desplazar2+"px"; //preparar para código CSS fondo del fondo 1
         fondo1.style.left=posicion1; // sirve para cambiar la posición del fondo 1
         fondo2.style.left=posicion2; //sirve para cambiar la posición del fonndo 2
         }
function repetir() { //temporizador para repetir el ciclo
         fondo1.style.left="0px"; // sirve para poner la posición inicial del fondo 1
         fondo2.style.left="450px"; //sive para poner la posición inicial del fondo 2
         desplazar=0; // sirve para poner la posición inicial
         }
            

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Para poder cancelar un temporizador (setTimeout o setInterval) es necesario asignarlo a una variable.

Te sugiero usar buenas prácticas:

1. Definir todas las variables que vayas a usar, ya sea en contexto global o limitada al lugar donde serán usadas. Se definen anteponiendo la palabra reservada `let`.
2. No uses eventos dentro de etiquetas `<button onclick="funcion()">` porque, a la larga, te va a complicar el mantenimiento de tus proyectos.
3. Desde javascript selecciona el elemento y asigna el evento deseado con `elemento.addEventListener()`. De esta forma, siempre tendrás todo en Javascript y no será necesario modificar el HTML en caso de cambios de comportamiento.

```js
// Declarar variables globales
let fondo1, fondo2, mover1, mover2, boton;
let desplazar = 0;

window.onload = function() { 
    fondo1 = document.getElementById("fondouno"); 
    fondo2 = document.getElementById("fondodos");
    // Asignar temporizador a variables
    mover1 = setInterval(mover, 50); // sirve para iniciar el temporizador
    mover2 = setInterval(repetir, 2250); // sirve para iniciar el segundo temporizador
    // Obtener botón y asignar evento
    boton = document.getElementById('Parar');
    boton.addEventListener('click', pararReiniciar);
}

function mover() { 
    desplazar-=10; // desplaza el fondo -10px
    // Definir variables que solo serán usadas dentro de la función
    let desplazar2=desplazar+450; //sirve para mover el fondo 2 a la vez
    let posicion1=desplazar+"px"; //preparar para código CSS fondo del fondo 1
    let posicion2=desplazar2+"px"; //preparar para código CSS fondo del fondo 1
    // Aplicar estilo a elementos
    fondo1.style.left=posicion1; // sirve para cambiar la posición del fondo 1
    fondo2.style.left=posicion2; //sirve para cambiar la posición del fonndo 2
}
function repetir() { //temporizador para repetir el ciclo
    fondo1.style.left="0px"; // sirve para poner la posición inicial del fondo 1
    fondo2.style.left="450px"; //sive para poner la posición inicial del fondo 2
    desplazar=0; // sirve para poner la posición inicial
}
// En cada clic del botón
function pararReiniciar() {
    // Si el temporizador está activo
    if(mover1) {
        // Cancelar temporizadores
        clearInterval(mover1);
        clearInterval(mover2);
        // Asignar valor nulo para poder reactivar
        mover1 = null;
        mover2 = null;
    } else {
        // Temporizador no está activo, volver a asignar
        mover1 = setInterval(mover, 50);
        mover2 = setInterval(repetir, 2250);
    }
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; }
h1 { font:bold 1.5em arial; text-align: center; padding: 0.5em ; } /* sirve para poner el texto central con el tipo de letra seleccionado*/
#visor { position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 200px; width: 450px; /*sirve para poner el texto en la posición seleccionada*/
         height: 300px; overflow: hidden; } /* características de la letra*/
#fondouno { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; } /*sirve para posicionar el fondo 1*/
#fondodos { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 450px; } /*sirve para posicionar el fondo*/
#micoche { position: absolute; top: 180px; left: 120px; } /*sirve para posicionar el coche*/
/* #Parar { position: absolute; right: 250px; top: 90px; color: red;  } */
```

```html
<h1>Coche en movimiento</h1>
<div id="visor">
   <div id="fondouno">
      <img src="fondoCoche.gif" alt="fondo1" > <!--utilizamos alt para que si la imágen no carga aparezca el texto (fondo1) -->
   </div>
   <div id="fondodos">
      <img src="fondoCoche.gif" alt="fondo2" >
   </div> <!--utilizamos div para crear seccionas-->
   <div id="micoche">
      <img src="coche.gif" alt="elCoche" >
   <div> <!--En este apartado metenemos las imágenes con el código img y le damos un nombre (id) para nombrarlo más adelante-->
</div>
<div>
    <button id="Parar" input type="Parar"> Parar </button>
</div>
```

Ahora solo queda un problema por resolver: Al parar los temporizadores y volver a reactivar, es probable que pase demasiado tiempo para que se ejecute nuevamente la función `reiniciar()` que, de hecho, me parece que está de sobra y sería suficiente con la función `mover()`, donde debes analizar el valor de `desplazar` para reiniciar ahí mismo.

Intenta solucionarlo y, si no puedes, edita la pregunta para poner el código actualizado.